# Flutter Android Firebase Messaging add custom icon for notification

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebasemessaging

I am using `firebase_messaing` inside my Flutter app. I can receive notifications on the Android Simulator, but the icon is just a bordered circle:

[image]

How can I change that icon?

Comment: I have the same problem, but the below solution not work for me. Can you show me the code? or replay to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347002/flutter-local-notification-from-firebase-not-showing-icon-to-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Firebase messaging gets the app icon as the notification icon.

It displays like that because emulators and some Android devices, don't decode the icon on the notification bar if it is not transparent, make sure to make the app icon transparent and it will be visible.

If you want you can customize the icon by doing this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

For more information, check https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

```
void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
          //      one that already exists in example app.
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

icon: 'launch_background' you can try to change icon from here.